# How to return IDs with specific conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I want to do is as follows:

1. Get min(Date) and max(Date) for each ID
2. Get result values from the date we got at step (1)
3. Check the value has increased or decreased

Is it possible to index in SQL?

| ID | Date | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| idid1 | 2016-01-01 | 0.6 |
| idid1 | 2017-02-01 | 0.7 |
| idid1 | 2018-03-01 | 0.65 |
| idid2 | 2017-01-11 | 0.2 |
| idid2 | 2018-02-21 | 0.3 |

Expected result:

| ID | Date | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| idid1 | 2016-01-01 | 0.6 |
| idid1 | 2018-03-01 | 0.65 |
| idid2 | 2017-01-11 | 0.2 |
| idid2 | 2018-02-21 | 0.3 |

I can retrieve step (1) but stuck from the step (2).

Comment: please share expected output from above resultset. Also, tag correct database. Is it Mysql or sql-server?

Comment: ```SELECT DISTINCT SIGN(FIRST_VALUE(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date DESC) - FIRST_VALUE(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date ASC)) AS change_direction FROM your_table```

Comment: What to do if the value has not changed?

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags; the OP will need to [edit] their question to (re)tag the correct (R)DBMS

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about structure of your result set...you can try this and change accordingly.

```
with t as(
    SELECT ID, MIN(Date)min, MAX(Date)max
    FROM Temp
    GROUP BY ID
    )
SELECT t.ID, t.min , t.max, min.Result min_result, max.Result max_result, CASE WHEN min.Result<max.Result  THEN 'Increased' ELSE 'Decreased' END IsIncreased
FROM t
INNER JOIN Temp min on(min.Id = t.Id and min.Date = t.min)
INNER JOIN Temp max on(max.Id = t.Id and max.Date = t.max)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Don't name a column "date", that's a SQL keyword. Use something like "created_on", and it's more descriptive.)

Normally you'd use `group by` to get the min/max.

```
select id, max([date]), min([date])
from example
group by id
```

But you also need the `result` for the min and max rows. This means you can't aggregate, you need the actual min and max rows.

You can get this with the [`row_number`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-row_number/) window function to assign a rank to each row per id.

```
select
  id, [date], result,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by [date] desc) as first,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by [date] asc) as last
  from example
```

Now we can treat that a table using a [Common Table Expression](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cte/) and select only those with first=1 and last=1.

```
with minmax as (
  select
    id, [date], result,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by [date] desc) as first,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by [date] asc) as last
    from example
)
select
  id, [date], result
from minmax
where first = 1 or last=1;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/8wdFZdHt).